# how to find who used SA for login in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

In an organization if a community used one SA account for a database. So, Is there a way in SQL server to find that person who used SA password and logged in as a user ?

Comment: Do you mean catch them in the act the next time they log in, or find out who logged in as them yesterday? Of course the real solution for this is to change the sa password and stop giving it to people you obviously can't trust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> community used one SA account for a database.

This is a big security risk, since your "SA" password is a known password in your organization. "SA" is the most elevated privilege account that if misused will cause a disaster and/or data breach by internal people.

I agree with @AaronBertrand, that you should not give "SA" password out to people you do not trust. IMHO, "SA" should be disabled (or atleast change its password on frequent basis), since there are other ways wherein you can give people access following [principle of least privilege](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/12/bad-habits-to-kick-ignoring-the-principle-of-least-privilege) to get their work done. SQL Server does not have [LAPS (like windows server now has)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3062591), so you have to design and implement a process that changes "SA" password on frequent basis. Below are some things that you can do to *limit* `sa` use *(see reference cited below for more information article by - K. Brian Kelley)*:

- Set a hard to guess password.
- Rename sa.
- Disable sa.
- Ensure that no other accounts exist named sa.

> So, Is there a way in SQL server to find that person who used SA password and logged in as a user ?

Given above points, SQL Server does not have an easy way of detecting what users/applications are using "SA" to connect. I have implemented a **light weight server side trace** that can be used to find out applications/users/host name that uses "SA" to connect. **[Script can be found here](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/31d781b0fae1de40d0aa)** and below is the sample output :

[image]

For complete automation, you can use [`TRACE_FILE_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/trace-file-close-event-class) WMI event to trigger import of trace file into sql server database table.

Alternatively, you can *gradually* move away from SQL Server authentication to Windows Authentication.

Refer to :

- [SQL Server 2012 Security Best Practices](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjABahUKEwiRj4afq7nIAhUJ8j4KHbMmAeI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F8%2FF%2FA%2F8FABACD7-803E-40FC-ADF8-355E7D218F4C%2FSQL_Server_2012_Security_Best_Practice_Whitepaper_Apr2012.docx&usg=AFQjCNFNrqRQqLTEwRcCR5zXD1jIPSZVEw&sig2=-eCvDfwwPH-7Cp6ooiZS9A) --> *(direct Word doc download)*
- [Best Practices to Secure the SQL Server sa Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3695/best-practices-to-secure-the-sql-server-sa-account/) - by K. Brian Kelley
- [How to Get SQL Server Security Horribly Wrong](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/how-to-get-sql-server-security-horribly-wrong/)

Comment: Highly useful and important info & links, for any aspiring DBA.  I plan to check out the light-weight trace script you linked at GitHub; I'll let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL Server version is 2008 or higher, then you can use the Audit feature to log and track events in the engine.

More information on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386%28v=sql.110%29.aspx